# Recordset not fetching all rows in excel macros

Tags: excel, recordset, vba

I am trying to fetch data into excel from sybase using recordeset.
the table has appx. 1 lakh rows but excel shows only limited number of rows appx 10k.
Following is a snippet reflecting what i am trying to do :

```
Dim DB_Con As ADODB.Connection
Call GetConnection(Impact_DB) 
Set DB_Con = ThisWorkbook.cnn_dlt
Call ThisWorkbook.Execute_Query("scratchdb..abc", "A2", DB_Con)

GetConnection(Impact_DB):
cnn_dlt.Open "DRIVER={MERANT 3.60 32-BIT Sybase};Srvr=" + server + ";DB='" + db +"';Uid=" + user + ";Pwd=" + `enter code here`passwd

Execute_Query:
rst As New ADODB.Recordset
TmpSqlTxt = "select * from " + Tbl_Name
rst.Open TmpSqlTxt, Impact_DB, adOpenStatic
row_cnt1 = rst.RecordCount
WS.Range(Range_Start).CopyFromRecordset rst

WS.Select
WS.Cells.Select
WS.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

rst.Close
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Select
```

What seems to me is that recordset is not able to fetch all rows.. as i tried displaying the count of recordset and it was 10k only.

Comment: Try setting the page size like this:  `cnn_dlt.PageSize = 1000` This will enable paging and will get past the 1000 record limit.  [See this article](http://www.rlmueller.net/ADOAlternatives.htm) for more info.

Comment: This does not work for me as there exists : 1186 pages and 11859 records. Although the table has more number of records.

Comment: How is `Range_Start` defined? Please note that `CopyFromRecordset` writes to the range, but does skip additional rows if the range is not sufficiently large. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa165427%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `.RecordCount` is wrong. To determine the proper record count, you will have to use `.MoveLast` on you record set first. See http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html for more details.

```
 rst As New ADODB.Recordset
 TmpSqlTxt = "select * from " + Tbl_Name
 rst.Open TmpSqlTxt, Impact_DB, adOpenStatic
 rst.MoveLast    
'^^^^^^^^^^^^
 row_cnt1 = rst.RecordCount
```

Comment: ok, still the count is same. Also the rows that gets fetched into excel are also less. I have 1 lakh rows in table but excel has only 11859 rows.

Comment: The select statement is not fetching all the records.

Comment: In the code you've provided, no records are fetched, so please show the relevant code.

Comment: The code itself is large and has subroutines.. this is the main logic through which i am fetching the data..

Comment: That may all be well and true, but we cannot do guesswork. Provide the minimum level of code required to show your problem - especially the part that eventually uses the record set you're retrieving in the snippet shown.

Comment: I have added the further code by which i am displaying the data.